# why isn't my gitignore working?

Tags: git

I have a `.gitignore` file like this:

```
./dist/
```

However when I get the unstaged changes

```
$ git status
```

the `dist` directory is still shown as changed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were the `dist` files already committed to the repo?

Comment: You need to `git -rm` the files first, if they are already part of the repository.

Comment: No, the files were not already committed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: @dopatraman if `git status` shows them as _changed_, that means they are already added and committed to the repository. New files are listed as _untracked_.

Comment: Also, there's no need for `./` at the beginning of the .gitignore line, just use `dist/`

Comment: @dopatraman Are you absolutely sure that the dir does not contain committed files? Try doing `git log -- dist`. Does that give any output?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Try this (backup your ./dist/ directory before proceeding):

```
git rm --cached
```

The above command will remove ignored files, so you can expect your "./dist/" directory to be removed. From the next time you change anything inside this directory will be ignored.

**Solution 2:**

Remove "./dist/" directory manually and commit. If you create the same directory once again it will be automatically ignored.

If nothing works, check your .gitignore file.

Comment: I never committed the dist directory

Comment: Somehow your dist directory is being tracked. u can try with the above solution.

Answer (score -1):

If the files were already committed, you need to clear the cache. Please follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository).

Comment: Have you try it  ?

Comment: Everyone is posting the same answer as I provided. I don't understand why I get downvoted

Answer (score -1):

Use git rm command to achieve it.

```
 git rm -r --cached your-ignore-folder-name
```

Comment: I never committed the dist directory